# Build command failed on telegram

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, telegram

I got this error on the last version of the telegram.

telegram source code version: 4.9.0

envirement :
ubuntu 17.10.0

android studio:3.2 canary 9

ndk version: 14.1.3816874

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm  : tmessages.28 <= TgNetWrapper.cpp
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./jni.c: In function 
'listdir':
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./jni.c:193:31: error: 
'struct stat' has no member named 'st_atim'
                 if (attrib.st_atim.tv_sec != 0) {
                           ^
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./jni.c:194:35: error: 
'struct stat' has no member named 'st_atim'
                     if (attrib.st_atim.tv_sec < time) {
                               ^
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./jni.c:198:35: error: 
'struct stat' has no member named 'st_mtim'
                     if (attrib.st_mtim.tv_sec < time) {
                            ^make: *** 
[/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates
/ndkBuild/afat/ 
debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/tmessages.28/./jni.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from 
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./tgnet/TLObject.h:13:0,
             from 
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./tgnet/ApiScheme.h:15,
             from 
 /home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./TgNetWrapper.cpp:2:
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./tgnet/Defines.h: In 
function 'std::string to_string_uint64(uint64_t)':
/home/joker/telegram490/TMessagesProj/jni/./tgnet/Defines.h:184:32: 
error: expected ')' before 'PRIu64'
 int len = sprintf(buf, "%" PRIu64, value);
```

**Edit:**

thanks to @anubhav-gupta, Through SDK Manager, I can only upgrade to version r18-beta1.

after the upgrade I face up with this error:

`Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared`

**Edit:**
update NDK to r15 and The problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in this line `'struct stat' has no member named 'st_atim'`
If you're using a modern version of the NDK, you'll have a modern struct stat: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/include/sys/stat.h

Note that you need to be using the NDK's unified headers to get the up to date headers. This is the default in r15, but opt-in for r14.

Comment: thanks, Through SDK Manager, I can only upgrade to version r18-beta1.

after the upgrade I face up with this error:
`Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared`